# How could I disable windows effects through batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, themes

Is it possible to disable these options shown in the picture below using a batch file. I am making a program that can boost a computers performance can any one help. my OS is windows 7 32bit

[image]

Comment: This is probably off topic. That's a sysadmin task.

Comment: I don't know where else to ask and other websites just say the manual way not how to do it through batch.

Comment: You could ask at either http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com for sure. You just need to say that you want to automate the setting in a batch file. What you need to know is how to control the setting, not the code. So, is it a registry setting, or is there an admin tool to control this?

Comment: I have sent it here [link](http://superuser.com/questions/686840/how-could-i-disable-windows-effects-through-batch)

Comment: would suggest you to check `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects]` registry keys through `REGEDIT.EXE` and then to use `REG` command or prepared `.reg` file and `REGEDIT` import command line options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To disable the effects

```
sc stop uxsms
```

To enable the effects

```
sc stop uxsms
```

You have to run it as Admin.

Like npocmaka said you have to change the value of the registry key :

```
[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects]
"VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000002"
```

With one of these value :

```
"VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000002 <-2 = All Settings Off

"VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000003 <- Manual Settings

"VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000001 <- Let's Windows choose.
```

EDIT : Here the keys you can set to 00000000 (off) or to 00000001 (on)

```
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects]
  "VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000003

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\AnimateMinMax]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\ComboBoxAnimation]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\ControlAnimations]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\CursorShadow]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\DragFullWindows]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\DropShadow]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\DWMAeroPeekEnabled]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\DWMEnabled]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\DWMSaveThumbnailEnabled]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\FontSmoothing]

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\ListBoxSmoothScrolling]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\ListviewAlphaSelect]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\ListviewShadow]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\MenuAnimation]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\SelectionFade]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\TaskbarAnimations]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\Themes]

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\ThumbnailsOrIcon]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\TooltipAnimation]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects\TransparentGlass]
  "DefaultApplied"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: It does boost performance but I already have a script that does this in the program and it dosnt help with the question.

Comment: See the EDIT to set the value in the registry. But the SC stop uxsms make exactly the same but temporaly. It effectively no set the value in the registry.

Comment: It works but it disables them all and I need it to disactivate each one individually

Answer (score 5):

To create a batch file that adjusts the performance options change to one of these (to keep the visual style see below)-

Let Windows Choose:

```
[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects]
"VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000000"
```

Adjust for Best Appearance:

```
[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects]
"VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000001"
```

Adjust for Best Performance:

```
[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects]
"VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000002"
```

Custom:

```
[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects]
"VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000003"
```

If you want to retain the Visual Style, which doesn't change it to the classic theme, use this:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ThemeManager]
"ThemeActive"="1"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ThemeManager]
"ThemeActive"=-
```

[Also see this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/73d72328-38ed-4abe-a65d-83aaad0f9047/adjust-for-best-performance)

Answer (score 0):

I created this today in case anyone wants to use a PowerShell script:

0 = Let windows choose what's best for my computer
1 = Adjust for best appearance
2 = Adjust for best performance

```psh
    $mode = 2
    $visualEffects = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects'
    if ((Get-ItemProperty $visualEffects).PSObject.Properties.Name -contains $name)
    {
      New-ItemProperty -Path $visualEffects -Name 'VisualFXSetting' -Value $mode -PropertyType 'DWORD'
    }
    else
    {
      Set-ItemProperty -Path $visualEffects -Name 'VisualFXSetting' -Value $mode  
    }
    Restart-Service -Name Themes  #(optional) to apply settings now
```