# Custom Advanced Performance area in Command Prompt?

Tags: powershell, command, settings, system

[image]

How can I customize this area with the Command Prompt or Powershell.  I have been looking everywhere but can't find information.   I would like to adjust it for best performance, Then customize a couple of check marked areas. Thank you.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516428/how-could-i-disable-windows-effects-through-batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516428/how-could-i-disable-windows-effects-through-batch)

Comment: I found the answer with this link